# How to send data from a python script to a hololens 2 app made with unity?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm trying to send a string from my computer to my hololens 2. I tried this method which seemed to work :

[Hololens TCP Sockets - Python Client to Hololens Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411832/hololens-tcp-sockets-python-client-to-hololens-server)

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error message when I launch the python client : "The remote system refused the network connection"

Are there more securities on the hololens 2 which prevent me to do this ?

Could you help me please ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you enable the network capability?

Comment: Yes. I checked the following capabilities : InternetClient, InternetClientServer, PrivateNetworkClientServer. Is it anything else I have to add ?

Comment: You can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets

Comment: And also see: https://mtaulty.com/2017/02/21/windows-10-uwp-hololens-a-simple-two-way-socket-library/